# WPF Combobox - Custom control when collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, controltemplate

Is it possible to show a custom control in the "collapsed part" of a WPF combobox? I mean the part above the popup when you click on the expand togglebutton.

There seems to be an "SelectionBoxItemTemplate" that defines the content when the combobox is collapsed, but that property is read-only. Is there a way to change that template, without overriding the whole combobox controltemplate?